# Getting 401 after successfully authenticate on Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt, token

I have this backend application running on Laravel 7.23.2 where I used tymondesigns / jwt-auth 1.0.0. The application is running on Linux.
The frontend is using Vue. The authentication happens just fine, I get the jwt token. After a successful authentication the frontend does several  api calls passing the token in head, but I keep getting this 401 error. The same code works just fine on my local computer.
I did change the jwt_secret and clear the cache, but still not working.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'namespace' => 'API'], function() {
     
    Route::get('/com/page/{pageSize}', 'ComController@all')->middleware('role:Admin');
    Route::get('/com/pesquisa/{anoMes}/{pageSize}', 'ComController@findByAnoMesAndFilters')->middleware('role:Informante|Gerente|Admin');
```

This is just a snapshot of my api.php file.
Does any one would have any idea what could be the main issue?
Let me know if further information is needed.
I´m also using https on the backend production, on localhost I use http.

Comment: Can you show us your real error ? Also, can you clear `laravel.log` file in `storage/logs`, and try again one time so you get the full error stored in that file ?

Comment: No error on the logs at all. What happens is, after a successful authentication, the application should show a dashboard, but instead it goes back to the authentocation page again. I can see there is a call to the backend, which is expected, but it fails. I will see if I can get a screenshot of it.
Another teste I did, but this time using the postman, was to move the api out of the secure route. The call was done successfully.

Comment: ```
 https://spi.test/api/comercial/page/20
401
1037 ms
GET /api/comercial/page/20 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS50ZXN0L2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMwNDUzMDQ5LCJleHAiOjE2MzA0NTY2NDksIm5iZiI6MTYzMDQ1MzA0OSwianRpIjoiUlJUbjdmR3BndW03YmtDRyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiZjZiNzE1NDlkYjhjMmM0MmI3NTgyN2FhNDRmMDJiN2VlNTI5ZDI0ZCIsIm5vbWUiOiJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIGRhIFNpbHZhIiwiZW1wcmVzYSI6MjQsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AdGVzdC5jb20iLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJBZG1pbiJdfQ.4m7hzEYGd3AwSYSVBNuiohoDtDbCzLp-N5lHV-LumkM

```

Comment: User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 1745352d-b1fa-4b3c-96b4-a646795cf1c0
Host: api.test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjhjQWRUMEtKOWZBRjBSREF5cVZxaUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiY0RKY3dtNURyaWptcmJ2SE1lS1NpclFra0tEWEdvdG5MeE4rd0podnh5YXRmbE56ODRxdmxyb0dIU0V6akIyUnNQSXk1NGJxTWhpckRoUnFhZ3RpSzEzY0hTRWZwNFgyek1aNUFObmxINmd5bXhzaUZxc3BwN3RjTisrZ04xUFciLCJtYWMiOiIyZWYzYTZjOGY0NGI4NmQxNjdkNDUyZjYzNmJiODc0YjJhMWFjZWQ3YjdmNjIwZjUyNzc4MDAyZWRjMmJjMGU1In0%3D;

Comment: some_session=eyJpdiI6IjU3NnB1Ry8yZXAvTHREcWUxeEl4d3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib2FJeWxYM3gvRm1oMldmR3Avd0QwS1pXOEoycnRwWVhESVY4V3ZVN1M4b1p3ZHVsS0R3Q0MzNTlYYnpBV2d5WS9VMkVaMEo3Sy93TGcwUCs2UEFpd05xbDUzNkZJaDJ1OUtMaWtIYXFSeVU2aVpnaUdVOUdoQ3ZjZURjSFRpdUwiLCJtYWMiOiI4MzVkZTg4MTE1NDg5MzI3MjNiOTViMTQzYzE2MGM5ZmFmYjdiMWNiZDY0MWNmMDg5MzJiN2I0NWQxODE5YzVhIn0%3D

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 23:49:59 GMT
Server: Apache
www-authenticate: jwt-auth
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, Authorization, accept, client-security-token
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8